# Find out which node (that shares the same category bitmask with other nodes) collided with my player node [Swift & Scenekit]

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a player node and multiple obstacle nodes that are continuously spawned at random until the game ends. Each obstacle node has a different name, but they all share the same category bitmask name, 'obstacle'.

Is it possible, since they all have unique names, to identify which particular obstacle the player collided with? Or would they all need unique category bitmasks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `SCNPhysicsContact` and `SCNPhysicsContactDelegate`. That will give you the exact nodes that collided.